# how to move selectbox from left to right?

Tags: html, css

I want to move selectbox from left side to right side on my page.
But when I do so it will reverse the whole select box
from
[image]

to[image]

I want it in original form on right side too.

my selectbox code is

```
<form class="myform">
<select name="recordPerPage">
<option value="30">30 Rows</option>
<option value="40">40 Rows</option>
<option value="50">50 Rows</option>
<option value="40">60 Rows</option>
<option value="70">70 Rows</option>
<option value="80">80 Rows</option>
<option value="90">90 Rows</option>
<option value="100">100 Rows</option> 
</select>
</form>
```

And css is

```
.myform
{ 
  direction: rtl; 
}
```

Comment: Why did you change the text-direction?

Comment: to move select box try to use float:right... not direction

Comment: thanks Kiran. Actually I am new on css. thats why I was trying the wrong thing.

Comment: @Hussian what you are trying to achieve is not possibly 'off-the-shelf' using CSS. Check out my edited answer below for solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    .myform
    {
    float : right;
    }
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

The `direction` property is related to **text** direction not element positioning.

Try this instead.

**CSS**

```
.myform {
    float:right;
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rak3Y/)

Comment: Just a note; if you only want to move the `<select>` (as opposed to the entire form) use `.myform select` as the selector instead of just `.myform`